# file type determine

Tags: compression

As part of the product, there were several scripts which was provided.

In one of the scripts, I've found the following line which seems not to work properly

```
find . -name *.old -type f -mtime +7 | xargs compress -f
```

when executing the `file` command on one of the *.old files I get the following result: `ASCII text, with very long lines`

Do you have any suggestion what could be done?

Comment: “which seems not to work properly”: so what did you expect it to do, and what did it do instead? And how is this related to the `file` command? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

The output of the `file` command is kind of irrelevant with regards to why the `file` command sequence would fail.

Apart from the output from the orignal `find` command, what is most interesting is what is the output from:

```
find . -name *.old -type f -mtime +7
```

if there are no file names echoed, then `compress` will be called without arguments, therefore waiting for stdin. If there are spaces in the file names of the files found, then `xargs` will have problems handing this over to compress as well.

You should at least try to change this into:

```
find . -name "*.old" -type f -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty compress -f
```

Updated based on the OP comment this would be:

```
find . -name "$FILE" -type f $ACTION_TYPE +$PARAM -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty compress -f
```

The `-print0` for `find` with the `-0` make sure filenames with spaces get properly passed to compress.
The `--no-run-if-empty` prevents `xargs` from running `compress` if no file is found at all.

Comment: Quoting "*.old" would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Sukminder you are absolutely right, I will update my answer for that.

Comment: OK. actually the command is:
find . -name "$FILE" -type f $ACTION_TYPE +$PARAM | xargs compress -f
when the $FILE=*.old   How to change the script?

Comment: I have extended the answer.If this solves the issue, make sure to update the title of your question, which has probably little to do with the file type.

Comment: Anthon, you didn't got my point. Even though the script seems to be OK, the quotations mark wasn't parsed to the command

Comment: @user1977050 Have you tried to escape the quotes with backslashes? `find . -name \"$FILE\"`?